# Apache2.2 FallbackResource Not Working?

Tags: apache2

So I have the fallbackresource configured in Apache to send requests to an index.php in the webroot and it seems to work except when I call a non-existent php file in the webroot directory. For example, if I try to get "/a.php", which doesn't exist, I get a 404 error. But if I call "/nodir/a.php", it sends this to the index.php file as expected.

I have searched google and read the Apache documentation for this feature but haven't found out why this is happening.

My Setup
Server version: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
Using default website with default config with "FallbackResource /index.php" under the directory section

Any ideas?

I am able to get this working correctly using mod_rewrite with the following basic lines in .htaccess but would obviously prefer the FallbackResource instead:

```
(.htaccess in webroot)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond /var/www/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond /var/www/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /a.php HTTP/1.1
HOST: localhost
Connection: close

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 31 Dec 2011 02:37:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.3
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 43
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

/a.php
localhost

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: Bug likely filed by same author: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52403